# Trying to set up the test program using iphone-twitter. URLShortener error

Tags: objective-c, xauth

Okay, *UPDATE*, I am now receiving the following errors, please help!

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.app/Test normal i386
cd /Users/rahulvarshney/Documents/newbieC/956Family/956Family/iphone-twitter/Example
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -L/Users/rahulvarshney/Documents/newbieC/956Family/956Family/iphone-twitter/Example/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.2/Symbols/usr/lib -F/Users/rahulvarshney/Documents/newbieC/956Family/956Family/iphone-twitter/Example/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/rahulvarshney/Documents/newbieC/956Family/956Family/iphone-twitter/Example/build/Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.build/Objects-normal/i386/Test.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics -licucore.A -o /Users/rahulvarshney/Documents/newbieC/956Family/956Family/iphone-twitter/Example/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test.app/Test

ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.0.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Please anyone. HELP!

**Original Post**

Hello, I am simply trying to run the test program included in the following API:
https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter

I get this error when compiling:

error: expected ')' before 'URLShortener'

It's from TwitterComposeViewController.m line 75, which is the following line:

```
- (void) shortener: (URLShortener*) shortener didSucceedWithShortenedURL: (NSURL*) shortenedURL
{
 // Replace the first URL in the message. This is terrible code that needs to be replaced with a proper regular expression.

 NSMutableString* message = [NSMutableString string];

 for (NSString* word in [_message componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]) {
  if ([word hasPrefix: @"http://"] || [word hasPrefix: @"https://"]) {
   [message appendString: @" "];
   [message appendString: [shortenedURL absoluteString]];
  } else {
   [message appendString: @" "];
   [message appendString: word];
  }
 }

 _textView.text = message;
 [self updateCharactersLeftLabel];

 [self _showComposeForm];
 [self _hideStatus];
}
```

I'm a n00bie, so apologies in advance. Any help is appreciated,

Thanks,

Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of that code. I'm sorry for the confusion, I need to update the documentation.

You need to do two things:

First, define TWITTER_USE_URLSHORTENER in your target settings.

Then, download https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-bitly and include those sources in your project.

Comment: Sweet Jesus! Thanks St3fan! I don't feel like such a n00bie any more =^)

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out.

Comment: Hi St3fan, I've made some progress, and followed your instructions. But what about RegexKitLite.m and RegexKitLite.h? Do these need to be added to the project as well?

Okay, I've spent an hour trying to debug this. Here's my debugger output:

Answer (score 0):

Usually when problems like this *error: expected ')' before '* were reported in my own app, it's because I forgot to import some of the necessary header files in that .m file.

So I suggest you check your code and see weather "URLShortener.h" (or something like that) were imported properly or not.